# detect a button click without getElementById

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

In [jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter), there is a button pointed out by red arrow

[image]

Which could be used to summon up a inner command palette

[image]

Which is actually an input and a list of `<li>`

The key function of the button is `data-jupyter-action="jupyter-notebook:show-command-palette"`

```
<button class="btn btn-default" title="open the command palette" data-jupyter-action="jupyter-notebook:show-command-palette"><i class="fa-keyboard-o fa"></i></button>
```

I guess I need a javascript snippet to handle `data-jupyter-action` attribute.

Usually, script can identify the element by `getElementById` but this button doesn't have an `Id`.

How can I detect the button clicking and **respond** "jupyter-notebook:show-command-palette" action?

Answer (score 2):

You can use querySelector instead of getElementById.

querySelector select elements with css selector.

```
let elem = document.querySelector('[data-jupyter-action="jupyter-notebook:show-command-palette"]');
```

This will return the element if it exists. It returns undefined if not found.

Comment: you could also do it by class